# C#, yield return - MoveNext() не меняет значение Current

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

Мне не понятно почему в обеих случая выводит в консоль 0, когда в первом случае выполняется MoveNext(), а во втором не выполняется?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace tetst
{
    public class A
    {
        static IEnumerable<int> test()
        {
            yield return 0;
            yield return 5;
            yield return 10;
            yield return 20;
            yield return 50;
        }
        
        static void Main()
        {           
            IEnumerator<int> t = test().GetEnumerator();//первый случай
            t.MoveNext();
            Console.WriteLine(t.Current);//0
            
            IEnumerator<int> x = test().GetEnumerator();//второй случай
            //x.MoveNext();
            Console.WriteLine(x.Current);//0
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы получить первый элемент, сначала надо вызвать `MoveNext()`, в противном случае `Current` просто не будет проинициализирован. То есть второй случай - это ошибка использьзования энумератора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Дело в том, что пока вы не сделали ни единого "шага" - `MoveNext()`, значение `Current` будет содержать значение по-умолчанию. А значение по умолчанию для `int` - это 0. По-этому, может показаться, что `MoveNext()` ни на что не влияет.

Я немного упростил ваш код и поменял первый `yield return` так, чтобы он возвращал тройку:

```
var enumerator1 = Test().GetEnumerator();
enumerator1.MoveNext();
Console.WriteLine("With MoveNext():    " + enumerator1.Current);

var enumerator2 = Test().GetEnumerator();
Console.WriteLine("Without MoveNext(): " + enumerator2.Current);

static IEnumerable<int> Test()
{
    yield return 3;
    yield return 5;
}
```

Теперь при запуске кода мы увидим следующий вывод:

```
With MoveNext():    3
Without MoveNext(): 0
```

Вы можете изучить что генерирует компилятор для этого кода в [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSAsA3OugG4CGY2AplBALbVjnAD2YS2AvNgCrUBnYAAoAlADoA4tWABROo2ZswY4mloMmLdknEBZVqWoA5agA8RotXgCcwgEQB1AJbAAFtgNHTFsSGwB2PbYANQ0ClrKugDCEGBgtMBWJGgUVBqK2mAI3HyCllIy8ppK7Krotg4u7qwQwJ6GJuaW/sFhGZHsCOKx8YnJaBVIAGy4SADMADzOUMAAfHlCYugA3uiBY5xwAOzY42obeFu7AKxqAL5AA), собственно так я и узнал ответ на ваш вопрос :)

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Буду теперь знать. По не знанию можно так и ошибок в реальных программах наделать.